My loop for buttons that play sounds doesnt work
I have buttons that will play instruments sound everytime they are clicked on. So that, starting to understand the process  i created an array with all the sounds, then, created a new Audio () for every item in the button, and tones array. It means creating a loop that repeat the proceses for every array´s position.
I tried but did not work.
Can you help me answering this?
Thank you!
firs step:
var tones = ["sounds/crash.mp3","sounds/kick-bass.mp3","sounds/snare.mp3","sounds/tom-1.mp3","sounds/tom-2.mp3","sounds/tom-3.mp3","sounds/tom-4.mp3",]
var instruments = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");

    instruments[0].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var crash = new Audio(tones[0]);
        return crash.play();
    })
    instruments[1].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var kickBass = new Audio(tones[1]);
        return kickBass.play();
    })
    instruments[2].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var snare = new Audio(tones[2]);
        return snare.play();
    })    
    instruments[3].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var tom1 = new Audio(tones[3]);
        return tom1.play();
    })
    instruments[4].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var tom2 = new Audio(tones[4]);
        return tom2.play();
    })
    instruments[5].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var tom3 = new Audio(tones[5]);
        return tom3.play();
    })
    instruments[6].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var tom4 = new Audio(tones[6]);
        return tom4.play();
    })

//i created a var with the instrument name for every button, but it works with the same var name only changing the position for the array tones, example var audio = new Audio(tones[0]),var audio = new Audio(tones[1]),var audio = new Audio(tones[2]),var audio = new Audio(tones[3]);....


2nd step:

var tones = ["sounds/crash.mp3","sounds/kick-bass.mp3","sounds/snare.mp3","sounds/tom-1.mp3","sounds/tom-2.mp3","sounds/tom-3.mp3","sounds/tom-4.mp3"];
var instruments = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
for(i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++){
    instruments[i].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var audio = new Audio(tones[i]);
        return audio.play();
    });
}


after step 2 i expected to play instrument[0] with tones[0], instrument[1] with tones[1].....
The result was... nothing xD, it didnt play any button.

If you don't use var or let, i becomes a global variable.
When the event listener executes (on button click), it captures i. However, after the loop, its value is instruments.length, which exceeds the array bounds. This leads to tones[i] being undefined, causing no sound to play.
To fix this, declare i with let:
for (let i = 0; i < instruments.length; i++){
    instruments[i].addEventListener("click",function (){
        var audio = new Audio(tones[i]);
        return audio.play();
    });
}


Thank you, it works! and by the moment i tried your answer i noticed that my previous code was working as well... i just dont know why, but the day i posted the question it wasnt hehe...
